# I have a issue with Powershell and task schedule

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Hello in My Windows Server 2012 i was configuring a task schedule to run a Powershell file that operate something inside the Microsoft VMM. 
It was working perfect,

**Action 1-** Running the command

**Action 2-** Deleting the file

Now i imported this task into Windows 2016 after i Upgrade the Windows and its not working its only run the file but delete is not working only the run work and if i arranged the actions and make the delete first its working without any problem, There is something preventing the file from delete action.

This is my Task Schedule Config

**General Tab:**

[*] run whether user logged in or not

Configure for [ Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 ]

[*] run with highest privileges

**Actions:**

[1] First action that run the file

*Action:* Start a program

*Program:* C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

*Argument:* .\*.ps1

*Start In:* E:\command\Fast_Commands

[2] Second action that delete the file

*Action:* Start a program

*Program:* C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

*Argument:* Remove-Item ".\*.ps1"

*Start In:* E:\command\Fast_Commands

==============

Last thing when i choose [[*] run only when user is logged in] its working without any problem and all actions is done, Iam sorry if something not cleared i wish i could know the problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Remove-Item ".*.ps1"`what does this achieve? It should be `*.ps1` at the very least

Comment: its Argument: Remove-Item ".\\*.ps1" i don't know why i can't edit it

Comment: well, are you sure first step finishes before the second one starts?

Comment: Yeah its finished and the command run without any problem but second action not deleting the file

Answer (score 0):

My observations: 
I am not sure why you are using **.\*.ps1** in both the cases.

But still if the remove is not working , I would request you to use **-Force**. 
Are you running the task with highest privilege? . If not please consider that also.

I would like you to check the history of the task also in order to see the error or if the task is failing. Requesting you to provide screenshots also.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply iam using it in the first action to run any ps1 file inside the directory and in the second one to delete it. i don't know if there's any way to combine this actions into one action and i will provide you with the error:
Task Scheduler failed to start "\Ps File Runner" task for user "xxx\xxxx". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.

Comment: Have you seen the error i still wont be able to do the task

Comment: That happens when the user does not have the permission. put a log in the script to see if at all it is running like do some file operation inside the script.